# Item overlapping to first item Recyclerview

Tags: android

i am using this library for creating view like cards [CARD](https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView)

its working well but now same functionality i am trying to implemented using RecyclerView. i have done overlapping all view using this code :

```
  public class ItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int mSpace;

    public ItemDecorator(int space) {
        this.mSpace = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (position != 0)
            outRect.top = mSpace;
    }
}
```

now i want the animation of overlapping all items to  the first item when scrolling like library which mention.How can i achieve this or is it possible or not?

Answer (score -1):

I am not answering the question but just have and advice. Before using any library from github check the number of contributors and number of pull requests.

Comment: yes i have checked and got issue is that working slowly when no. of item increases thats why i am implementing using RecyclerView and thanks.